# this === window in firebug

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, this

I wrote a simple webpage as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>pop</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
document.write(this === window);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I browse this page using IE6 and FireFox 3.5.8, both give an answer ***true***. But when I press F12 in FireFox and type ***this===window*** in the console, it will give me an answer ***false***, why?

Great thanks.

---

So if ***this*** in firebug means the firebug object, how can I reference the normal ***this***?

Comment: as a note, the url `javascript:alert(this === window)` gives `true` so it's something to do with how firebug evals stuff. I read about this recently, trying to find where though.

Comment: If you can access the window through `window`, why do you want to reference it as `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *this* keyword inside firebug refers to the firebug object not the window object.

This is because of the scope of javascript execution.

Answer (score 3):

Because Firebug is a Javascript program running inside of Mozilla.  `this` in the Firebug console probably refers to the Firebug console itself.

Answer (score 2):

There is no normal `this`.  It's context-dependent, and the context of Firebug is /not/ the global context.  Other shells, such as [Squarefree](http://www.squarefree.com/shell/)'s, do run in the global context.

Answer (score 1):

> So if ***this*** in firebug means the firebug object, how can I reference the normal ***this***?

In your sample code `this` will be the `window` object because that is the Global Object when running in a browser. In Firebug the Global Object is Firebug itself (set a watch for both `this` and `window` in Firebug to confirm this).

From Douglas Crockford's [A Survey of the JavaScript Programming Language](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html):

> There is a special variable, called `this` that is set to the object when a method of the object is called. 
>   ...
>   In a simple function call, `this` is set to the Global Object (aka `window`)

Why are you trying to see if `this` is the `window` object anyway?